# Exceptions in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java and trying to understand Exceptions in Java.

```
class MyException extends Exception {  

      void someMethod () {  
            doStuff();  
      } 

      void doStuff() throws MyException {  

         try {  
             throw new MyException();  
          }  

          catch(MyException me) {  
             throw me;  
          }  
       }  
}
```

This Program gives the error:

> java:3: unreported exception MyException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
>
> ```
>  doStuff();
>          ^
> ```

The try and catch block are written within the `doStuff()` method. Also the `doStuff()` method "throws" `MyException`, then why do need to throw `MyException` in `someMethod()` also?

Comment: thats cause you threw the exception

Comment: just a note... Checked exception are pretty much a Java idiosynchrasy: they do *not* exist at the OOA/OOD level and there a **lot** of languages doing perfectly fine without that "concept".  Some go as far as saying that checked exceptions are: *a)* glorified GOTO statements,  *b)* a Java mistake that should have been left out of the languages,  *c)* to be avoided at all costs (the *Spring* framework comes to mind, but it's far from the only one).  You also have a *lot* of language running on top of the JVM that decided to let this "feature* out of the language...

Comment: for example... 250 000 medium codebase here where we didn't define a single checked exception and where we're not throwing a single checked exception.  So take what you read about checked exceptions with a **huge** grain of salt. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did indeed catch MyException, but you re-threw it, so a new, active exception needs to be caught.

This is called a checked exception.  Anytime you call the doStuff() method, you need to wrap it in a try/catch for MyException OR you can declare that your method will also throw MyException.

This guarantees that known exceptions will be at least thought about in the coding process.

Comment: That the exception was re-thrown is not really the main issue. The point is that doStuff() is *declared* to be able to throw the exception, and the exception is checked, so you must handle it (or allow it to propagate) in someMethod().

Comment: @davmac -- you are correct, but if it is declared, but never thrown, it would be just as valid a fix to remove the throws clause...

Comment: @Joe Zitzelberger -- not necessarily, the exception specification is part of the method interface. You may want the possibility that subclasses can override the method definition in such a way that causes the exception to be thrown. In any case, my point was that the asker was getting an error, and the error was due to the method being declared to throw an exception, not due to it actually *throwing* the exception.

Comment: @davmac -- you are correct, but I think you are sorta missing the point.  The OP is trying to learn about exceptions in java, and it sounds like at a basic level.  OP needs to grasp the way exceptions work before he starts declaring exceptions for future expansion.

Comment: @Joe Zitzelberger -- your answer is technically wrong, and giving a wrong answer isn't the right approach to helping a beginner. The question asks why someMethod() must (be declared to) throw MyException (as per the compiler error message), and the answer is because (a) doStuff() is declared to throw it and (b) it is a checked exception. The fact that the exception is thrown, caught and re-thrown within the body of the doStuff() method is irrelevant, but you've made it seem important in your answer. And the point about future expansion wasn't for the OP's sake, but for yours.

Comment: @davmac -- I was pretty correct in saying that "...called a checked exception.  Anytime you call the doStuff() method, you need to wrap it in a try/catch for MyException..." so I'm not sure why you think it is wrong, I covered the half of the problem that you are complaining about.

Comment: @Joe -- it's wrong that the re-throwing of the MyException instance is what causes the compiler error. To match this exactly with your own words, it's wrong that "... you re-threw it, so a new, active exception needs to be caught". The re-throwing of the exception has nothing to do with why the compiler complains about the exception not being handled in someMethod().

Answer (score 3):

You Need to "**rethrow**" the Exception from someMethod because MyException is a "**Checked Exception**" (doesn't extend RuntimeException - which is an "**Unchecked Exception**") and the compiler forces you to handle Checked Exceptions, like this:

```
class MyException extends Exception {

    /**
     * @throws MyException because it is a checked Exception (doesn't extend RuntimeException) and the compiler
     * forces you to handle Checked Exceptions.
     */
    void someMethod() throws MyException {
        doStuff(); 

    }

    void doStuff() throws MyException {
        try {
            throw new MyException();
        } catch (MyException me) {
            throw me;
        }
    }
}
```

Or you need to handle the MyException in some Method so the compiler is happy, like this:

```
class MyException extends Exception {


    void someMethod() {
        try {
            doStuff();
        } catch (MyException ex) {
            //Do Something useful with the Exception...
            Logger.getLogger(MyException.class.getName()).severe("A Severe Exception Message");
        }

    }

    void doStuff() throws MyException {
        try {
            throw new MyException();
        } catch (MyException me) {
            throw me;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what you have in the body of the doStuff() method - because you've declared that it "throws MyException", then the calling method(s) - in this case someMethod() - must either handle the exception (via a try/catch block) or be declared to throw the same exception themselves. In the latter case, the exception if thrown by doStuff() will automatically propagate through to the caller of someMethod().

In other words: the fact that you catch the exception in doStuff() doesn't matter, because doStuff() is declared to throw the exception anyway. You could even remove the method body of doStuff() (making it do nothing) and you would still have to handle the exception in someMethod().

Answer (score 2):

Since doStuff() is again throwing the exception. You will have to wrap it around a try catch again.

```
void someMethod () {  

      try
      {
        doStuff();  
      }
      catch ( MyException e )
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }
```

Or another option is not to throw the exception again. Everytime you throw an exception it has to be caught.